# PC Switcher for USB Hubs?

Tags: usb, usb-hub

I have a small problem with one of my USB hubs. It is a personal hub that I use for multiple computer/android-based (chromium/androids) devices that is used to serve as a hub for several devices like mic headsets, usb mouse, usb keyboard, and the occassional flashdrive. My problem is that I constantly have to unplug it and replug it back into the device I want to use it with.

Like for example, I have a PC in which I write all of my programs, and play video games, and I have an Android Tablet, where I keep all of my personal stuff. I have an adapter that allows me to plug regular USB 2.0 stuff into the android's microusb port including a usb hub. Now, I don't want to use a separate keyboard, mouse, and headset for each device, if both devices are in the same workstation area. So, my question is there some sort of "USB switch" I could use? A switch that connects both of my "workstation" devices to a single USB hub, and has some sort of button that all I have to do is press it to change what device the hub "belongs" to instead of unplugging and replugging in the hub?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a KVM, but do not wish to use the display switching capabilities.

Comment: Little problem is that the answers to the suggested "similar" question are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there used to be a company "SMSC", now a part of Microchip Technology, who were (and are) making USB hub chips with two upstream ports. From [description](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/USB2524):

*"USB2524 is the industry's first USB switching hub that combines a USB Hi-Speed hub and switching functionality in a single device. Equipped with two upstream ports and four downstream ports, USB2524 enables USB device sharing and switching between two USB hosts without "cable swapping". Requiring no more than standard USB hub driver support, the USB2524 appears as a 4-port USB hub to either USB host system and supports standard USB topology."*

I believe [I/O-Gear](https://www.iogear.com/usb-switch.htm) did use this chip for retail products.
This is another [example](http://www.monoprice.com/Product?p_id=2995&gclid=CL_hnavUrs8CFQYLaQodAZYG5g).
[image: Monoprice switching hub]

Most notable application is called "USB Printer Switch"